# How boiled eggs can help in weight loss?

Tags: weight-loss, eggs

I have not joined the gym for exercise but only walk of 30 to 45 minutes before my breakfast and after the dinner. In breakfast i take a cup of tea with a slice of brown bread, and in lunch a small bowl of salad and some chicken or fish, in dinner i eat Chapati with some vegetable dish. Do I need eggs too for weight loss?
Should i add/remove some foods to lose weight?
How boiled eggs can help me in weight loss and what should be the quantity and timings like, in breakfast, lunch etc. or any time(when i want)?

Comment: As I said in my other comment, please take the tour and read the help section. This is another question that is very vague and only has a very peripheral relation to fitness. How are you trying to lose weight? What is your workout program? What are you eating currently that you think changing to boiled eggs will help? Etc.

Comment: @JohnP Did the question is according to rules now, I edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hard one. as an answer for your egg eating question. the whites of the eggs are the part with less saturated fats and cholesterol.so if your trying to lose weight with egg just eat the whites. yokes do carry other nutritional benefits but for losing weight purposes the whites are best. timing can be anytime. qtys i would have 4 egg whites in a serving. with a bit of salt and pepper. your lunch meals seem perfect. also your morning walk before your meal is great.

Egg whites are a low-calorie, fat-free food. They contain the bulk of the egg’s protein. The egg white contains about 4 grams of protein, 55 mg of sodium and only 17 calories. A single egg white also offers 1.3 micrograms of folate, 6.6 mcg of selenium, 2.3 mg of calcium, 3.6 mg of magnesium, and 4.9 mg of phosphorus and 53.8 mg of potassium.